# Mixin to override inherited method

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I have a collection of classes, A1, A2, A3 etc, which all have method `m()`. I also have class B with method `m()`. I want to easily be able to create classes C1, C2, C3 etc. which call `m()` from class B, while also having all other properties of A1, A2, A3 etc...

The issue I'm having, however, is that in class C1 the method `m()` from class B should call `m()` from the class A1.

I'm having a hard time putting into words what I want, but the the way I'm currently thinking about doing this, is using mixins. C1 would inherit from A1, with a mix-in of B. However, I don't know how to make `m()` in B call the correct `m()` from one of the A classes.

So, my two questions:

- Is there a name for what I'm trying to do?
- What would be the correct way to do this?

Edit: As requested, a concrete example:
The method `m(p)` in A1, A2, A3 etc all calculates a matrix `M`, for some parameters `p`. I want to create classes C1, C2, C3 etc, which behave in the same way as A1, A2, A3, *except* for method `m()`. The new method `m()` takes a longer list of parameters `p`, of size N, and we calculate `A*.m()` N times and then return the sum.

The code to calculate the sum of `m()` is the same for all of the A* classes. In the proposed mix-in solution above, the summing code would be in B. Both B and A1 would be inherited to form C1. However, the method `m()` in `C1` from B would have to call `A1.m()`.

Comment: can you give some examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you just need `super` which redirects the call to a parent or sibling class (depending on the MRO).

For example:

```
class A1(object):
    def m(self):
        print('Calling method m of class A1')
        self.data *= 2

class A2(object):
    def m(self):
        print('Calling method m of class A2')
        self.data *= 3

class A3(object):
    def m(self):
        print('Calling method m of class A3')
        self.data *= 4

class B(object):
    def m(self, p):
        print('Calling method m of class B')
        for i in range(p):
            # You haven't specified which python you are using so I assume
            # you might need to most explicit variant of super().
            # Python3 also allows just using super().m()
            super(B, self).m()

class C1(B, A1):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
```

Just testing it:

```
a = C1(10)
a.m(10)
```

prints:

```
Calling method m of class B
Calling method m of class A1
Calling method m of class A1
Calling method m of class A1
Calling method m of class A1
Calling method m of class A1
Calling method m of class A1
Calling method m of class A1
Calling method m of class A1
Calling method m of class A1
Calling method m of class A1
```

and the saved value:

```
a.data
# returns 10485760
```

defining other `C` works too:

```
class C2(B, A2):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value

a = C2(10).m(2)
#Calling method m of class B
#Calling method m of class A2
#Calling method m of class A2


class C3(B, A3):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value

a = C3(10).m(1)
#Calling method m of class B
#Calling method m of class A3
```

Of course you want another logic and probably need to return values from `.m()` instead of modifying in-place but I think you can work them out for yourself.

The word you were looking for is probably [MRO (method resolution order)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). Hope this helps you.

Also of interest could be the documentation of [`super` (Python2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), [`super` (Python3)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#super).

And you can always check the `MRO` of a class by calling the `.mro()` method:

```
print(C1.mro())
[<class '__main__.C1'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A1'>, <class 'object'>]
```

So python starts by checking if `C1` has a method `m` and if not checks `B`. `B` has one so it is executed. The `super` call then just goes again into the `MRO` and checks if the next class (`A1`) has a method `m`, which is then executed.

Comment: You might want to clarify that `super()` doesn't always call a parent, it looks up the requested attribute in *the next class in the MRO*. As in this case, it can find a sibling class.